# HTML template does not exists

Tags: angularjs, meteor

Error: [angular-meteor][err][404] /packages/events/client/events/views/events-list.html - HTML template does not exists!

I have a locally created package in Meteor with an angular view and controller. The html files and controller files are are added properly. I was getting this error.

Solution:

The template cache contains all the compiled templates and the module directive templateUrl must have the exact match. The solution is /packages/kite:events/client/events/views/events-list.html.

Under the error is a the call stack, the top line being:
at Object.$provide.decorator.$delegate.get

Click on the link beside it, loading the source file. Set a breakpoint at var originResult, reload the page.

Open Closure originalGet  function scope and you will see the listing of the templatecache. If your templateUrl doesn't match any of these you will get the error.

Comment: Is there a question in this?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same thing and have fixed it by removing/creating again directive and template files. (Maybe it'll help to smbd)